# Can the files on the public directory in Laravel be viewed without knowing the name of files?

Tags: laravel

I am storing a file on the `public` directory. If my file is a 100 character random string, could someone potentially find this file? Is there any way to protect the `public` directory for Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not attempt to do this.  Security by obscurity is not a valid approach.

A few flaws to this approach:

- If I knew the file existed, but not its name: I could try every combination to find it.
- The web server may have an unknown flaw that allows directories to be listed?

If `HTTPS` is not utilized, anyone monitoring requests could see the file.

The best way would be to create a view that serves the file, stored outside the public directory(`/storage`), and secure the view with a single use token or login.